# JSF ConcurrentModificationException on datatable

Tags: java, performance, jsf, primefaces

We had an outage recently, and in the log of our application, we can see this exception.
Looks like the data in a table is being modified while primefaces is sorting ¿How is this possible?

This is something that doesn't happen frequently, it just happened once in a production enviroment.
Also this same stack trace repeats like ten or more times in seconds.

```
05-Jul-2022 19:13:53.583 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-746] com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.handleRenderException Error Rendering View[/pages/example.xhtml]
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1466)
    at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:177)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.SortFeature.singleSort(SortFeature.java:167)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.preRender(DataTableRenderer.java:141)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:93)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:949)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1912)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1908)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:918)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1905)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:638)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:405)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1747)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1747)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:423)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:342)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:65)
    at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:252)
    at org.omnifaces.context.OmniPartialViewContext.processPartial(OmniPartialViewContext.java:122)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:1124)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1905)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:465)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:194)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:151)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:151)
    at org.omnifaces.viewhandler.OmniViewHandler.renderView(OmniViewHandler.java:155)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:126)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:223)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:671)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at ar.com.dux.jsf.filters.CacheFilter.doFilter(CacheFilter.java:27)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at ar.com.dux.jsf.filters.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.GzipResponseFilter.doFilter(GzipResponseFilter.java:183)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:196)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:698)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:364)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:624)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:831)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1650)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

We are using JSF 2.3.9, Primefaces 8.0, Omnifaces 3.11, Tomcat 8 and the bean is ViewScoped (javax.faces.view.ViewScoped not omnifaces).

The page is very complex, but his basic function is to generate an invoice so we have a section for the client data, another section for products that are added to the invoice and another section for payment info (using facelets include).These last two sections have datatables with sorting, and are updated from all the other sections.

Comment: If you check the last line before the exception in the stack trace, you can see it occurred inside ArrayList code. Even though the name looks scary, it simply means that the list has been modified while iterating on it (Iterables throw that exception in case of modification of the collection while iterating). It doesn't necessarily indicate a real race conditions on your table, but most probably a bad for-loop that got into that state because of the outage (or not).

Comment: Thanks for the response, I know that this is because the list has been modified while being sorted. What I mean about by "how is this posibble" is how can this happen in JSF and which could be the cause.

Comment: PF/Jsf version? Scope of the bean bonded to the data table? AS used(jBoss/Tomcat/...)? Can you add an explanation of page structure and logic, if you can't post a simple example? My 2 cents, could be a sequence of actions that lead to an update of the data table, when the table is still sorting.

Comment: @WoAiNii I added that info and a brief explanation. The page is very complex, with a lot of components and updates. ¿Where should I start searching?

Comment: Maybe add primefaces source code and debug `org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.SortFeature.singleSort(SortFeature)` where it occured?

Comment: If you can reproduce somehow the problem, identify the data table, and try to see the browser console, to determine the sequence of calls occurring. If it repeats then there could be a sequence of actions that create a loop, so track who updates who, and see what could be the case. The analysis could be possible only with the code, or at last, a simplified version of the page.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible causes for that issue:

**Multiple threads working on the same list**

- A single thread that modifies the list while iterating over it (e.g. counted for or foreach)
- The second option should not be the cause here, as the stacktrace contains just a call to `ArrayList.sort`. I don't think, that the JDK is faulty at that place.

The first option is more likely:

**Simultaneous AJAX requests**

- `com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial` should be an indication, that this happens during AJAX
  Shared list due to wrong bean scope - e.g. session or even application
  Correct bean scope, but the list comes from a shared source

**You can try 1 of 2 solutions...**

- Wrap your backing bean list `Collections.synchronizedList.... List<Object> objList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Object>());`
- Try `java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList` https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html
  it's expensive to modify, but wait-free to read.